# What is the proper OOP approach for parsing responses from 4 different APIs?

Tags: python, oop

What is the proper approach to code, for example, a `Weather` class, which parses 4 different sources? Here's how I've done it:

Created a class named `Weather` with 4 attributes (such as `temp`, `windspeed`, `pressure`, `humidity`) and 4 methods such as `parse_source1`, …, `parse_source4`. To get results I create 4 objects and I call different methods on each one of them.

But now I'm confused if it is a proper approach for this problem. Maybe should I create `Weather` class with all attributes and afterwards use inheritance and put parsing into `init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm not sure this is a proper question to SO because there can be too many "right" approaches but, anyway, this is a problem I've found too many times and the same solution always worked to me, in various languages.*

I'd say it would be better to have a parser class for each object:

```
class JSONWeatherParser(object):
    def parse(self, value):
        json_obj =  json.load(value)
        w = Weather()
        # Do some stuff here, assign values from json_obj to w etc.
        return w

class XMLWeatherParser(object):
    def parse(self, value):
        element = xml.etree.ElementTree(value)
        w = Weather()
        # Do some stuff here, assign values from element to w etc.
        return w

class YAMLWeatherParser(object):
    def parse(self, value):
        w = Weather()
        # Sorry, I do not even know what it looks like
        return w
```

It can be cool to put the classes on a dict, too:

```
weather_parsers = {
    'xml': XMLWeatherParser,
    'json': JSONWeatherParser,
    'yaml': YAMLWeatherParser
}
```

Now you could simply do:

```
format = request.get('format') # For example
data = request.get('weather')
parser = weather_parsers[format]()
weather = parser.parse(data)
```

In fact, in Python you do not even need these `*WeatherParser` classes: you could create `*_weather_parser` *functions*, which would be simpler:

```
def json_weather_parse(value):
    json_obj =  json.load(value)
    w = Weather()
    # Do some stuff here, assign values from json_obj to w etc.
    return w

def xml_weather_parse(value):
    element = xml.etree.ElementTree(value)
    w = Weather()
    # Do some stuff here, assign values from element to w etc.
    return w

def yaml_weather_parse(value):
    w = Weather()
    # Sorry, I do not even know what it looks like
    return w
```

If your parser are going to do one and one thing only *and* the parser does not preserve state, functions are a better choice. OTOH the class approach is more generic, language-independent and powerful. The point is, you may not need that much power.

**Summing up**: Although in theory it would be cool to make different `Weather` classes for each behavior (all the kids are doing it! - or they were, in the 90's) in practice it seems to be more manageable to separate the parsing concern from the model.

**EDIT**: Hannes Ovrén made an excellent question.

Indeed, parser classes are more complex, I'd rather use parser functions. Now, why not make them `Weather` methods? Well, parsing some specific class' instance does not feel as the behavior expected from this class, so it seems better scoped to put this concern in a different place. Surely we would not expect a non-existent instance to parse itself!

For sure, we could put it on a class method, as it is done in Django et al., but why create a method if a function will do it? In this case, it is more related to style and I play by [these old school rules](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) ;)

More importantly, this is in a sense a style question and my approach would be the described one. However, I know this is only one approach and there are many other ones as useful and "right" as this one. I don't think class methods are wrong, but I would not use them either.

Comment: Many thanks for your extensive answer, after what I have read it looks so obvious now. I am definitely going to use your approach.

Comment: Why do you feel that it is better to have separate parser classes that instances `Weather` objects, instead of sub-classing? You are not really providing *any* arguments for it.

Comment: @HannesOvrén good question. My answer became too big so I answered as a edit in my post.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to separate your `Weather` class from the code for parsing, i.e.

```
class Weather:
    def __init__(...):
        ...

def parse_weather(source):
    if source == ...:
        ...
    return Weather(...)
```

This way your class doesn't have to change when you add or remove sources. You could even create a separate class;

```
class WeatherParser:
    def __init__(source):
        ...
    def parse_weather(...):
        ...
        return Weather(...)
```

Which would contain your parsing methods

Answer (score 1):

If you are the sole implementor of the class, I'd use `@classmethod` decorators to create factory functions. This way the parsers/sources are easy to find since they are part of the `Weather` class.

```
class Weather(object):
    def __init__(self, temp, windspeed, humidity, pressure):
        # Initialize everything ...

    @classmethod
    def from_source1(cls, source1):
        # Parse source 1, get temp, windspeed, humidity and pressure
        # ...
        instance = cls(temp, windspeed, humidity, pressure)
        return instance


weather = Weather.from_source1(source1)
```

If you expect other people to use your class, and might want to implement their own sources, then I think you have two good options:

1. Do parsing in `__init__` and let user sub-class your `Weather` base class.
2. Make a `WeatherParser` baseclass and let users inherit from that.

I think the first option is more intuitive, since you avoid creating more classes.
The most important thing (in my opinion) is that there is no question on the correct way to add new sources.